# Display hidden text input field javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to display the hidden text field for user to enter if they had chosen particular drop box's value.
here is my snippet code

```js
var cCust = document.getElementsByName('customerType');
cCust.onchange = cType;

function cType(){
  var cCust = document.getElementsByName('customerType');
  var selectValue =  cCust[0].options[cCust[0].selectedIndex].value;
  
  alert(selectValue);
  
  if (selectValue == "trd"){
   document.getElementById('tradeCustDetails').style.visibility ="visible";
   document.getElementById('retCustDetails').style.visibility="hidden";
   
  }
  else{
   document.getElementById('tradeCustDetails').style.visibility ="hidden";
  }
  
 }
```

```html
<form id= "bookingForm">
<section id="placeOrder">
   <h2>Place order</h2>
  
   Customer Type: <select name="customerType">
    <option value="">Customer Type</option>
    <option value="ret">Customer</option>
    <option value="trd">Trade</option>
   </select>

   <div id="retCustDetails" class="custDetails">
    Forename <input type="text" name="forename" value=""/>
    Surname <input type="text" name="surname" value ="" />
   </div>
   <div id="tradeCustDetails" class="custDetails" style="visibility:hidden">
    Company Name <input type="text" name="companyName" />
   </div>
  </section>
    </form>
```

There is no error shown in console. 
Here is the reference that I refer to. [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/2AALG/)
It changes the getElementById to getElementsByNames according to my form attributes.
Is there anything I missed or mistake??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your `onchange` event handler is not being assign to your select element is because the `document.getElementsByName('customerType')` will return an array and not the exact reference. You should be pointing to your index `0`. See below:

```js
var cCust = document.getElementsByName('customerType');
cCust[0].onchange = cType;
function cType(){
  //var cCust = document.getElementsByName('customerType');
  var selectValue =  cCust[0].options[cCust[0].selectedIndex].value;
  
  alert(selectValue);
  
  if (selectValue == "trd"){
   document.getElementById('tradeCustDetails').style.visibility ="visible";
   document.getElementById('retCustDetails').style.visibility="hidden";
   
  }
  else{
   document.getElementById('tradeCustDetails').style.visibility ="hidden";
  }  
}
```

```html
<form id= "bookingForm">
<section id="placeOrder">
   <h2>Place order</h2>
  
   Customer Type: <select name="customerType">
    <option value="">Customer Type</option>
    <option value="ret">Customer</option>
    <option value="trd">Trade</option>
   </select>

   <div id="retCustDetails" class="custDetails">
    Forename <input type="text" name="forename" value=""/>
    Surname <input type="text" name="surname" value ="" />
   </div>
   <div id="tradeCustDetails" class="custDetails" style="visibility:hidden">
    Company Name <input type="text" name="companyName" />
   </div>
  </section>
    </form>
```

Comment: As i follow the reference, all of the attribute used is ID, `getElementById`. However in my form, it using `getElementsByName`, What i don't understand is why we have to assign an array to `getElementsByName` while `getElementById` do not need?

Comment: `getElementsByName` will tend to get all the elements and will return a collection of that element/ s while `getElementById` will get the first instance of the element with the corresponding ID. That' why it is used for referencing a specific element unlike the `getElementsByName`. If you want to use `getElementById` on your select, provide an ID to it.

Answer (score 1):

Why you dont use direct onchange event in html?

```
<select name="customerType" onchange="cType()">
    <option value="">Customer Type</option>
    <option value="ret">Customer</option>
    <option value="trd">Trade</option>
</select>
```

**Snippet**

```js
var cCust = document.getElementsByName('customerType');
cCust.onchange = cType;

function cType() {
    var selectValue = cCust[0].options[cCust[0].selectedIndex].value;

    alert(selectValue);
    debugger;
    if (selectValue == "trd") {
        document.getElementById('tradeCustDetails').style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById('retCustDetails').style.visibility = "hidden";

    } else {
        document.getElementById('tradeCustDetails').style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

}
```

```html
<form id= "bookingForm">
 <section id="placeOrder">
  <h2>Place order</h2>

    Customer Type: 
  <select name="customerType" onchange="cType()">
   <option value="">Customer Type</option>
   <option value="ret">Customer</option>
   <option value="trd">Trade</option>
  </select>
  <div id="retCustDetails" class="custDetails">
            Forename 
   <input type="text" name="forename" value=""/>
            Surname 
   <input type="text" name="surname" value ="" />
  </div>
  <div id="tradeCustDetails" class="custDetails" style="visibility:hidden">
            Company Name 
   <input type="text" name="companyName" />
  </div>
 </section>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `onchange` were not firing. I think you can carry on with the following:

```js
function cType(){
    var cCust = document.getElementsByName('customerType');
    var selectValue =  cCust[0].options[cCust[0].selectedIndex].value;
    
    alert(selectValue);
    
    if (selectValue == "trd"){
        document.getElementById('tradeCustDetails').style.visibility ="visible";
        document.getElementById('retCustDetails').style.visibility="hidden";
        
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('tradeCustDetails').style.visibility ="hidden";
    }
    
}
```

```html
<form id= "bookingForm">
<section id="placeOrder">
      <h2>Place order</h2>

      Customer Type: <select name="customerType" onchange="cType()">
          <option value="">Customer Type</option>
          <option value="ret">Customer</option>
          <option value="trd">Trade</option>
      </select>

      <div id="retCustDetails" class="custDetails">
          Forename <input type="text" name="forename" value=""/>
          Surname <input type="text" name="surname" value ="" />
      </div>
      <div id="tradeCustDetails" class="custDetails" style="visibility:hidden">
          Company Name <input type="text" name="companyName" />
      </div>
  </section>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue was with the way you invoked `onChange` for `customerType`. I removed it from your script and added it as an attribute to the html as `onChange="cType(this)"`. This way every time the value of the dropdown changes, function `cType` is called with the current context (this) as parameter.

Hope this helps :)

```js
function cType(){
  var cCust = document.getElementsByName('customerType');
  var selectValue =  cCust[0].options[cCust[0].selectedIndex].value;
  
  alert(selectValue);
  
  if (selectValue == "trd"){
   document.getElementById('tradeCustDetails').style.visibility ="visible";
   document.getElementById('retCustDetails').style.visibility="hidden";
   
  }
  else{
   document.getElementById('tradeCustDetails').style.visibility ="hidden";
  }
  
 }
```

```html
<form id= "bookingForm">
<section id="placeOrder">
   <h2>Place order</h2>
  
   Customer Type: <select name="customerType" onChange="cType(this)">
    <option value="">Customer Type</option>
    <option value="ret">Customer</option>
    <option value="trd">Trade</option>
   </select>

   <div id="retCustDetails" class="custDetails">
    Forename <input type="text" name="forename" value=""/>
    Surname <input type="text" name="surname" value ="" />
   </div>
   <div id="tradeCustDetails" class="custDetails" style="visibility:hidden">
    Company Name <input type="text" name="companyName" />
   </div>
  </section>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByName('customerType')` returns an array like object of elements with the attribute `name='customerType'`.

`document.getElementsByName('customerType')[0]` will return the first element with the attribute `name='customerType'`.

This should work

```
var cCust = document.getElementsByName('customerType')[0];
cCust.onchange = cType;

function cType() {
  var cCust = document.getElementsByName('customerType')[0];
  console.log(cCust.options[cCust.selectedIndex].value)
  var selectValue = cCust.options[cCust.selectedIndex].value;


  if (selectValue == "trd") {
    document.getElementById('tradeCustDetails').style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementById('retCustDetails').style.visibility = "hidden";

  } else {
    document.getElementById('tradeCustDetails').style.visibility = "hidden";
  }

}
```